# SQL sum columns base on column "type"

Tags: sql

I have a view like this one

```
col1 col2 col3 year class type
1    3    4    2017 A     1
4    5    7    2017 A     2
3    4    2    2017 A     3
3    1    1    2017 A     4
1    1    1    2017 B     1
0    0    2    2017 B     2
2    2    0    2017 B     3
```

What I want is to create a new view based on the above one, I want to sum columns of the same year if "type" isn't 1. If type=1 new value is "yes", if type!=1 "no".

```
col1 col2 col3 year class new
1    3    4    2017 A     yes
10   10   10   2017 A     no
1    1    1    2017 B     yes
2    2    2    2017 B     no
```

How can I do this?

Comment: can you include your attempt as well?

Comment: how is the "new" col generated?

Comment: Yes = 1, No != 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this.

```
SELECT 
    SUM(col1) col1, 
    SUM(col2) col2,
    SUM(col3) col3,
    year,
    class,
    (case when type = 1 then 'yes' else 'no' end)  as new 
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY year, class, (case when type = 1 then 'yes' else 'no' end)
```

Result:

```
col1        col2        col3        year        class new
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----- ----
10          10          10          2017        A     no
1           3           4           2017        A     yes
2           2           2           2017        B     no
1           1           1           2017        B     yes
```

Answer (score 0):

depending on your table it would be something like the following

```
SELECT SUM(col1), SUM(col2), SUM(col3), year, class
FROM table WHERE type <> 1
GROUP BY year, class
```